# Bottom navigation behaves differently for starting destination

Tags: android, viewmodel, bottomnavigationview, android-jetpack-navigation

Hey recently I had discovered this weird behaviour of bottom navigation when I setup with NavController.

**Problem**

Only the start destination in navigation graph for bottom nav, saves its state. While others don't.[That means onDestroy is never called for starting destination only]. Now the issues with this is ViewModel associated with starting destination nav graph never gets cleared.

**Behaviour I am looking for**

How to make starting destination lifecycle behave as all the other destinations, so on destination change the viewModel will be cleared?

Code snippet :

```sh
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/nav_main"
            app:startDestination="@+id/nav_main_home">

    <include
            android:id="@+id/home_fragment_graph"
            app:graph = "@navigation/nav_main_home"/>

    <include
            android:id="@+id/profile_fragment_graph"
            app:graph = "@navigation/nav_main_profile"/>


    <include
            android:id="@+id/message_fragment_graph"
            app:graph = "@navigation/nav_main_message"/>


</navigation>
```

```
nav_main_home -nav_graph- for HomeFragment
nav_main_profile -nav_graph- for ProfileFragment
nav_main_message -nav_graph- for MessageFragment
```

Now when I switch from HomeFragment to ProfileFragment or MessageFragment the onDestroy for HomeFragment is not called. But when I switch from ProfileFragment or MessageFragment the onDestroy is called for both of them.

Comment: Some code might help.

Comment: Are you tied down to the NavController? It would be easier to accomplish this manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fragments (and by extension Navigation) save the state of fragments on the back stack. As per the [Principles of Navigation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-principles), the start destination of your graph should always be on the back stack and that's why you go back to the start destination when you hit back from one of the other bottom nav items and why it retains its state. You should never be purposefully throwing away the user's state.

The reason other bottom nav items don't keep their state is that once you switch off of them by hitting another bottom nav item, they are no longer on the back stack and hence Fragments destroy and throw away any state associated with those Fragments.

There's an existing [issue for supporting multiple back stacks](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/80029773) which would cause every bottom nav item to save its state and restore it when you go back to it. As that issue is not yet fixed, there is a [NavigationAdvancedSample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/tree/master/NavigationAdvancedSample) that offers a temporary workaround to get that behavior.

Comment: Hey Ian, thanks for the insides and references. So that means if I need to clear viewmodel, I should do it manually when onDestroyView is called?

Comment: The Fragment is going to restore its savedInstanceState (including the state of all views) when the user hits the back button / rotates their device. You shouldn't be clearing your ViewModel for Fragments that are on the back stack.

Comment: Hey Ian,

I am getting savedInstanceState non-null except for start destination, the first bottom tab fragment. Any idea how to get savedInstanceState non-null for start destination tab when we tap start destination tab again ? version 2.5.2